# I am trying to include quotes in the href command for HTML and it won't work

Tags: java, html, bookmarklet

`

```
     <a href="javascript:function gcloak() { var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');link.type = 'image/x-icon';link.rel = 'shortcut icon';link.href = 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/infinite_arrow_favicon_5.ico';document.title = 'My Drive - Google Drive';console.log(document.title);document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link) };gcloak();setInterval(gcloak, 1000);">Google Drive Disguise</a>
```

I want to make a hyperlink so you can drag that code onto your bookmarks bar but the code comes short, showing as `<a href="javascript:function gcloak() { var link = document.querySelector(`

I can't change the javascript code and i have no idea what to do. any help would be much appreciated.

I tried replacing the quotes but that didnt work.

Comment: java ? really ?

Comment: firstly, please fix the tags of the question, or explain how it relates to Java. Secondly, I would assume that you need to escape the quotes as `\"` or `&quot;` (depends on your context first if its javascript, second one if its plain HTML render) in order for them to not be recognized as part of the tag syntax